# Email attachment parsing via mime4j

Tags: java, perl, smtp, mime

I am using a small java smtp library (http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/), by this I need to parse the incoming emails in separate components viz body, attachments etc.

I am trying to use mime4j , but the documentation suggests that mime4j can only give  event notification or  token notification and nothing else. For stripping out body and attachments etc I had to use my own custom logic inside the event handlers. Is my observation correct?

If yes then how can I use mime4j to use for my requirement. Please suggest.

I badly need an approach that takes in the smtp data stream and returns me with an array of attachment references or streams in fully parsed out form in java. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Comment: Meanwhile, on self investigation, I found a perl library MIME::PARSER being used in amavisd-new. The mailing list guys from amavisd-new told me that a decoded mail object just like what i require can be refered in from amavisd-new perl script, but is it possible that i could use it from perl into java?

Comment: I have ran into the same problem as you and while googling noticed your name all over this place (mailing lists, forums). Thank you for saving me time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mime4j can definitely do what you need. Make a subclass of org.apache.james.mime4j.message.SimpleContentHandler, and implement the bodyDecoded method. Then pass this subclass into a MimeStreamParser instance. You'll see that bodyDecoded is called once per body or attachment, and the stream it gives you contains the data with Base64 or Quoted-Printable decoding already performed.

If you don't like event-based APIs in general, you can try the more DOM-like functionality exposed via the org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message class. You can call Message.getBody() and then see if what it gives you back is an instance of Multipart, TextBody, BinaryBody, etc. If Multipart, then you can call Multipart.getBodyParts to recurse into the subparts.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, now i am facing problem in recreating mails sent from iphone, the mail headers have "X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (7D11)" , can anybody tell me what custom logic i need to put to account for mails sent via iphones.

Comment: All problems resolved mime4j works much much much better than java mail api.

Answer (score 2):

@Ashish the other option since you are using SubEthaSmtp is to do what SubEtha Mail List manager does: http://code.google.com/p/subetha/source/browse/trunk/src/org/subethamail/common/SubEthaMessage.java

The linked class extends SMTPMessage and which has a bunch of getPart() methods. javax.mail.Part has most of what you need to turn an attachment into a file.

Comment: Adam, Currently I am using Java mail api itself for parsing email to strip out mail body and attachments into separate files. Reason I am looking on to mime4j is that java mail api fails at times and is not that fault tolerant for badly formatted mime messages (my experience) and mime4j promises that. So as an alternative I am looking into mime4j. I will post my detailed results soon.

Comment: Adam, mime4j is definitely a much better alternative to java mail api, It provides clean interface for implementation. My test results with mime4j (0.7) have been excellent.