# Email mime parsing

Tags: java, email, mime

I was trying to find a user friendly mime parser for java that could just get rid of all that message part parsing a user have to do. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675824/email-attachment-parsing-via-mime4j) for more info about my requirement.

Until now i have not been able to find one, so i think i need to write one for myself, that should be robust enough to handle all kind of emails. (I know this is not going to be easy.)

Since there are a ton of email RFC's , can somebody guide me in the right direction from where should i start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) add on and use classes like [MimeUtilty](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, now i am facing problem in recreating mails sent from iphone, the mail headers have "X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (7D11)" , can anybody tell me what custom logic i need to put to account for mails sent via iphones.